# How to retrieve the label information while using Keras's data generator?

Tags: python, keras

while using the Keras Python code below:

```
for x_batch,y_batch in datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory = os.path.join(dataset_root_path,dataset_train_path),
    target_size = (520,520),
    class_mode = 'binary',
    batch_size = 1
):
```

I got the x_batch and y_batch numpy array, the y_batch numpy array is encoded into the number 0.0 or 1.0 since I am using the "binary" class_mode, however, in this way, I lost the information about what is the real label for that sample, for example, "cat" or "dog". How can I retrieve the label information according to the output '1.0' and '0.0' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to instantiate the datagenerator and train with `fit_generator`:

```
train_gen = datagen.flow_from_directory( ... )
model.fit_generator(train_gen, ...)
```

You then can access (among other attributes) the class indices with `train_gen.class_indices`.